# How can I efficiently load a Large TileMap

Tags: lua, tiles, love2d

I want to make a survival game, with a as big as possible tile map. I am using the Love2D game engine with lua. Currently I am generating the map with a 2d array. This works well for perhaps a 10x10 tiles map. I want to make them as large as possible. At least 1000x1000-100000x100000. But that juat won work. I also thought about spliting it up in chunks but I have no Idea how. Would I split up theese chunks in other small tilemaps? Or how could I do that? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This question is too broad, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a minimal example of what you've got working? Also, I agree with @Mikkel, this is too broad. A simple search for "load map by chunks" may help.

Answer (score 1):

Read a bit about "Space partitioning" in general.
Pay attention to BSP/Quadtree/k-D tree, those are building blocks for pretty much anything.

If your chunks are equal in size, positioned in regular grid and has limited overall size, you can simplify everything greatly.
Store chunks in files under names that is composed of chunk indices by x/y axes. Such name would act as chunk's id, and filesystem will work as db storing the world. Some chunks may be missing completely, that means there's nothing in that part of the world.
When you need to show part of the map on screen, you check if you have needed chunks loaded already. You know coordinates of the part you need to show, you build chunk id, check some cache (lua table), and if chunk is not there - try to open the file with same name. If file is loaded successfully - add it to the cache, if not - add empty dummy to signal there's nothing to show.

Comment: So for every single chunck I should save them in a seperate file? Like when I have 500x 500 chunks that, would be 250000 files? And showing the loaded ones in a lua table, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, if every chunk is filled with data, then it will be 250k files. Or it might be a single database file. Love2D supports `sqlite3` db library via plugin, see Love2D wiki for details: https://love2d.org/wiki/SQLite3